# Zowe explorer VSCode Retrieving response from zowe.List Error: Huh?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftp, mvs

I am trying to connect to MVS tk4 using Zowe Explorer through ftp from my Visual Studio Code...

When I'm trying to locate data sets from Zowe Explorer in my Connection, I see this Error:
"Retrieving response from zowe.List Error: Huh?"

I want to add that I can connect to my localhost ftp using the specific port without username or password using smart FTP and I get all the data sets.

Also though I created a zftp profile I still see that I don't have one

[No Profile is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkYCT.png)

I can connect to ftp using terminal... and I can browse the data sets.
Is there a way to make it work in vscode

I appreciate any help ?